# Getting 404 not found when hitting spring boot end point

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

When trying to hit the rest api end point of spring boot application I get 404 not found, below is the project structure snapshot attached
[This is my project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9nSm.png)

Controller -

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserRestController {

    private final UserService userService;

    public UserRestController(UserService userService){
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST,
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public void createUser(@RequestBody final UserDTO user){
        userService.saveUser(user);
    }


}
```

Comment: Please add more details like sample url that you are trying to execute. Try to add swagger api spec for better understanding of the urls: https://www.baeldung.com/swagger-2-documentation-for-spring-rest-api

Comment: It is a component scanning issue, try to fix it by scanning controller beans too

Answer (score 0):

You are not scanning your controllers.

In the image you shared `@ComponentScan` only scans `Service` folder. But your controllers are in `RestController` folder.

Use `@ComponentScan` without any arguments. By default it will scan for `beans` in current folder and its sub folder.

e.g `@ComponentScan()`

Answer (score 0):

@SpringBootApplication covers @EnableAutoConfiguration, @ComponentScan, @Configuration.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST,
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```

and for this, you can simply do

```
 @PostMapping(value ="/create"
 consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```

Lets test it in postman, it should be `POST` and url must be
`localhost:<your port>/users/create`. Dont forget to add your UserDTO in your Postman Body.

In case you missing it, your application must be up and running.

Answer (score 0):

****imporatant** Please check your HTTP method type when call end point form postman.it must be "post"**

1. Bro if you are using Spring boot. then no need to write @EnableAutoConfiguration, @ComponentScan, @Configuration.
   @SpringBootApplication Covers all these.
2. You just check your url it should be like http://localhost:8080/users/create
3. used autowired
   @autowired
   private final UserService userService;